# problemas lista em python

Tags: python, lista

Estou tentando resolver este problema em python:

Faça um programa que carregue uma lista com os modelos de cinco carros (exemplo de modelos: FUSCA, GOL, VECTRA etc). Carregue uma outra lista com o consumo desses carros, isto é, quantos quilômetros cada um desses carros faz com um litro de combustível.

Calcule e mostre:

- O modelo do carro mais econômico;
- Quantos litros de combustível cada um dos carros cadastrados consome para percorrer uma distância de 1000 quilômetros e quanto isto custará, considerando um que a gasolina custe R$ 2,25 o litro.

Abaixo segue uma tela de exemplo. O disposição das informações deve ser o mais próxima possível ao exemplo. Os dados são fictícios e podem mudar a cada execução do programa.

Comparativo de Consumo de Combustível

```
Veículo 1
Nome: fusca
Km por litro: 7
Veículo 2
Nome: gol
Km por litro: 10
Veículo 3
Nome: uno
Km por litro: 12.5
Veículo 4
Nome: Vectra
Km por litro: 9
Veículo 5
Nome: Peugeout
Km por litro: 14.5

Relatório Final
 1 - fusca           -    7.0 -  142.9 litros - R$ 321.43
 2 - gol             -   10.0 -  100.0 litros - R$ 225.00
 3 - uno             -   12.5 -   80.0 litros - R$ 180.00
 4 - vectra          -    9.0 -  111.1 litros - R$ 250.00
 5 - peugeout        -   14.5 -   69.0 litros - R$ 155.17
```

O menor consumo é do peugeout.

Aqui em cima é como deve ficar. Segue meu código abaixo e o que está faltando fazer. Neste código que enviei só não estou sabendo como achar o menor valor do consumo, para imprimir o carro. Se alguém poder me ajudar agradeço.

Meu código:

```
listaCarro = [None] * 5
listaConsumo = [None] * 5
listaDistancia = [None] * 5
listaCusto = [None] * 5

precoGasolina = 2.25
distancia = 1000

for i in range(0,5):
    print ('Digite o nome {} carro: '.format(i+1))
    listaCarro[i] = input()

for x in range(0,5):
    print('Digite o consumo {} carro (km por litro): '.format(x+1))
    listaConsumo[x] = float(input())
    listaDistancia[x] = distancia / listaConsumo[x]
    listaCusto[x] = listaDistancia[x] * precoGasolina     

for j in range(0,5):
    print('Veiculo {}'.format(j+1))
    print('Nome: {}'.format(listaCarro[j]))
    print('Km por litro: {}'.format(listaConsumo[j]))

for p in range(0,5):
    print('{} - {}    -    {}  -  {} litros - R$ {}\n'.format(p+1, listaCarro[p], listaConsumo[p], round(listaDistancia[p],1), round(listaCusto[p],2)))
```

Answer (score 3):

Consoante os dados que apresentas podes fazer os calculos todos de uma só vez (no mesmo ciclo), assim como podes popular as duas listas também no mesmo ciclo:

```
listaCarro = []
listaConsumo = []

while len(listaCarro) < 5:
    listaCarro.append(input('Digite o nome do carro: '))
    listaConsumo.append(float(input('Digite o consumo do carro (km por litro): ')))
    print('novos dados inseridos\n')

results = ''
valor_gas = 2.25
total_km = 1000
for j, c in enumerate(listaCarro):
    print('Veiculo {}'.format(j+1))
    print('Nome: {}'.format(c))
    print('Km por litro: {}\n'.format(listaConsumo[j]))

    consumo_l = round(total_km/listaConsumo[j], 2)
    results += 'O carro {} consume {}L e custará $R{} quando fizer {}km\n'.format(c, consumo_l, round(consumo_l*valor_gas, 2), total_km)

print('O carro mais económico é o {}'.format(listaCarro[listaConsumo.index(max(listaConsumo))])) # descobrir na listaCarro o carro cujo o indice e o mesmo do que o indice do maior valor na listaConsumo
print(results)
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](https://repl.it/repls/TerribleKeyCarat)

NOTA: o carro que faz mais km por litro é o mais económico

Answer (score 2):

Outra solução, mais simples, porém fugindo do que foi solicitado explicitamente pelo enunciado, seria criar um objeto `namedtuple` para representar um determinado carro ao invés de armazenar os valores em listas distintas.

```
from collections import namedtuple
from operator import attrgetter

Carro = namedtuple('Carro', ('nome', 'rendimento'))

carros = [
  Carro(nome='Fusca', rendimento=7.0),
  Carro(nome='Gol', rendimento=10.0),
  Carro(nome='Uno', rendimento=12.5),
  Carro(nome='Vectra', rendimento=9.0),
  Carro(nome='Peugeout', rendimento=14.5)
]

carro_mais_economico = max(carros, key=attrgetter('rendimento'))

print('Mais econômico:', carro_mais_economico.nome)

for i, carro in enumerate(carros):
  consumo = 1000 / carro.rendimento
  gasto = 2.25 * consumo
  print(f'{i+1} - {carro.nome:<10} - {carro.rendimento:>5} - {consumo: >6.2f} - R$ {gasto:.2f}')
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/WetUrbanSoftwaresuite)</sup>

O resultado seria:

```
Mais econômico: Peugeout
1 - Fusca      -   7.0 - 142.86 - R$ 321.43
2 - Gol        -  10.0 - 100.00 - R$ 225.00
3 - Uno        -  12.5 -  80.00 - R$ 180.00
4 - Vectra     -   9.0 - 111.11 - R$ 250.00
5 - Peugeout   -  14.5 -  68.97 - R$ 155.17
```