# Preciso fazer uma entrada em Python armazenando como lista, tudo numa mesma linha

Tags: python, python-2.7, lista

Estou com dúvida em um exercício da faculdade, eu preciso armazenar 3 dados que são: Número do veiculo, quilômetros rodados e o consumo em cada variável do tipo lista, mas devido a serem tipos diferentes, com os 2 primeiros sendo inteiros e o último float, além de terem a entrada na mesma linha, eu não consigo armazena-los.

Pensei em tentar armazenar desta maneira:

```
idcar=[] #Numero de cada veiculo
kms=[]   #Quilometros rodados
consumo=[] #Consumo de cada veiculo
for i in range(10):
    idcar[i],kms[i],consumo[i]=map(float,raw_input().split())
```

E depois transformar os valores de float(o idcar e o kms), para inteiro mas para meu infortúnio aparece esse erro:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                              
  File "consumo1.py", line 17, in <module>                                      
    idcar[i],kms[i],consume[i]=map(float,raw_input().split())                   
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Sendo que as entradas são dadas desta maneira, com 10 valores diferentes:

1001 231 59.2

1002 496 60.4

**...**

**Adicionando informações importantes que eu esqueci de colocar:**
  No fim eu devo calcular o consumo médio(Km/L) para cada carro identificado e por fim na saída devo imprimir para cada carro seu consumo médio, além de dizer quais são os 2 piores consumos entre os carros.

Gostaria muito que pudessem me ajudar, desde já grato, espero que eu tenha escrito de maneira clara minhas dúvidas, é a primeira vez que escrevo aqui.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se os valores são relacionados entre si, não armazene-os em estruturas distintas, isso só aumentará a complexidade da sua aplicação. Será mais fácil você ter apenas uma lista e armazenar todos os valores nela, em uma tupla. Por exemplo:

```
veiculos = []
for i in range(10):
    identificador, quilometragem, consumo = raw_input().split()
    veiculos.append((int(identificador), int(quilometragem), float(consumo)))
```

Desta forma sua lista ficará parecia com:

```
veiculos = [
    (1001, 231, 59.2),
    (1002, 496, 60.4)
]
```

Onde o identificador é o índice 0 da tupla, a quilometragem o índice 1 e o consumo o índice 2. Para calcular o rendimento, basta fazer a divisão da quilometragem pelo consumo. Você pode definir uma função para isso:

```
def calcular_rendimento(veiculo):
    return veiculo[1] / veiculo[2]
```

E, assim, exibir o rendimento dos veículos:

```
for veiculo in veiculos:
    rendimento = calcular_rendimento(veiculo)
    print 'Veículo {} teve um rendimento de {:.2f} km/L'.format(veiculo[0], rendimento)
```

O que geraria uma saída parecida com:

```
Veículo 1001 teve um rendimento de 3.90 km/L
Veículo 1002 teve um rendimento de 8.21 km/L
```

Para obter os veículos com menor rendimento, leia sobre a função nativa do Python `min` e seu parâmetro `key`.

Mas para uma solução mais legível e idiomática, sugiro que leia esta [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/290835/5878).

Comment: Eu li o que sugeriu, realmente parece uma ótima maneira de realizar porém talvez seja pela minha inexperiência, não consegui inserir a entrada na tupla e armazenar devido aos valores serem inseridos na mesma linha, posteriormente o problema também pede para utilizar os valores do consumo e km para gerar o consumo médio(km/L) de cada carro identificado e no fim devo imprimir 2 menores valores  do consumo médio identificar o número do veiculo no qual eles estão atrelados, bem como imprimir em cada linha o número de identificação de cada carro e seus consumos médios.

Comment: @Vinícius adicionei mais alguns comentários na resposta; acredito que com isso você consiga terminá-la sozinho.

Comment: Resolveu o problema, foi bem rápido após ler as funções que foram muito importantes para o exercício.

Answer (score 0):

É possível passar uma lista dentro de uma lista.

```
dados = []

for i in range(2):
    codigo, KM, consumo = raw_input().split()
    dado = [codigo, KM, consumo]
    dados.append(dado)

for item in dados:
    print("Código: {}".format(item[0]))
    print("KM: {}".format(item[1]))
    print("Concumo: {}".format(item[2]))
```

Comment: Caso eu use isso eu recebo o erro no programa:                 
 `Traceback (most recent call last):                                              
  File "consumo1.py", line 16, in <module>                                      
    dado = [input(), input(), input()]                                          
  File "<string>", line 1                                                       
    1001 231 59.2                                                               
           ^                                                                    
SyntaxError: invalid syntax `

Comment: Poderia me informar o erro? coloquei o código no [repl.it](https://repl.it/@leobarbetta/veiculos) e está funcionando

Comment: Vou tentar mandar foto do que apareceu:                                           [link](https://imgur.com/a/WRonhuF)

Comment: Ali informa erro na linha 16, o código que mandei tem 10 linhas, tem como adicionar na pergunta o código todo?

Comment: Claro, ele está praticamente com seu código somente e a pequena alteração que foi a de remover de dentro dos inputs aquela formatação, pois o programa que verifica as entradas e saída que é o VPL, tem sérios problemas com isso. [link](https://imgur.com/a/79FwEV1)

Comment: mesmo com o texto dentro dos `inputs` está gerando esse erro? - Da uma olhada nesse [link](https://repl.it/@leobarbetta/veiculos)

Comment: Sim, acabei de testar continua com o mesmo problema, tem grandes chances de ser o VPL, não é raro ele ter esses problemas aleatórios, não taria passando tanta dor de cabeça se ele fosse otimizado pra isso, basicamente ele é feito voltado para a linguagem C que é padrão na faculdade na área do meu curso, embora tenha sua variação para Python, mas como pode ver tem bastante problemas, se for o caso só comunicando a equipe que cuida para tentar lançar uma nova atualização nele ou eu terei que buscar outra maneira de fazer essa entrada no programa.

Comment: O erro está em utilizar o `input` no lugar de `raw_input`. A primeira tenta analizar a entrada como código Python, gerando o erro de sintaxe; e chamar três vezes a função esperaria as entradas em linhas diferentes, não na mesma linha.

Comment: @Vinícius, atualizei o código, poderia testar de novo.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, nossa.. não sabia disso. valeu.

Comment: @Barbetta a pergunta é em Python 2.7, então use `raw_input` ao invés de `input`; e perceba que as entradas estão na mesma linha, então não há como utilizar três vezes a função.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, atualizei, mas sua resposta é 1KK de vezes melhor, +1 ;)